# Unexpected newline characters using nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working my way through an example using Nodejs & Express.  When trying it I get an error.

A portion of the main file:

```
    app.post('/send', express.bodyParser(), function(req, res) {
    if(req.body && req.body.tweet) {
        tweets.push(req.body.tweet);
        res.send({status:"ok",message:"Tweet received"});
    } else {
        res.send({status: "nok", message: "No tweet received"});    
    }
```

});

A portion of the test script:

```
    var req = http.request(opts, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf8');

var data = "";
res.on('data', function(d) {
    data += d;  
});
res.on('end', function() {
    assert.strictEqual(data, '{"status":"ok","message":"Tweet received"}');
});
```

});

This is the error:

```
assert.js:104
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "{\n  \"status\": \"ok\",\n  \"message\": \"Tweet received\"\n}" === "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"message\":\"Tweet received\"}"
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/jfb/Documents/Info/Nodejs/Up_and_Running/test.js:19:11)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1356:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
```

I checked my file with an editor set to display special characters and there were no newline characters as shown by the error message.

Could someone tell me what is happening here.

Thanks,  Jim

Comment: This issue has been added to the errata of the book in question: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920015956

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending an object in your response, which gets encoded into an actual JSON string by Express. Apparently Express adds some indentation in the formatting of the JSON string, which is perfectly valid. Your assertion tests that the JSON string is exactly the same as the actual Javascript source code that defines your original object; this is not something that can *ever* be guaranteed by *any* JSON encoder, as Express only sees your object but can never see the code that generates it and the presence or absence of meaningless whitespace in that code. In your tests, you should actually decode the JSON into a native object and deep-compare the resulting object with another object containing your expected state. The other option is to actually send a *string* instead of an object in the response; this way you can control the exact string representation of your response and not rely on external JSON encoding. This is *very* inflexible and gains you nothing in terms of testing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was curious because the example came out of a book and googling did not find anyone else with the same problem.  I thought I goofed up somehow.